# Testing an already running Activity using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I try to test a app which starts a special activity every time the app got started. Lets call this Activity `AlreadyStartedActivity`. The test case looks something like this:

```
public class AlreadyStartedActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<AlreadyStartedActivity> {

    public AlreadyStartedActivityTest() {
        super(AlreadyStartedActivity.class);
    }

    public void testStart() {
        Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());

        // use solo to click and test some features of the activity.
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `AlreadyStartedActivity` is configured in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.AlreadyStartedActivity"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

`singleTop` avoids the call to `AlreadyStartedActivity#onCreate` and this blocks the `getActivity` method forever.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this situation?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't properly setup test class. You need to add default constructor:

```
public class AlreadyStartedActivityTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<AlreadyStartedActivity> {

    public AlreadyStartedActivityTest() {
        super(AlreadyStartedActivity.class);
    }

    public void testStart() {
        Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());

        // use solo to click and test some features of the activity.
    }
}
```

And probably it is better to move `Solo` to `setUp()` method.

Comment: I know, and in the actual testcase I did all this things. To make it clear: The problem is the blocking `getActivity`-method. If I had missed the constructor I would got an Exception.

Comment: I have tested that code, and it works. It starts activity and call onCreate() method. I was using robotium-solo-4.0.jar. And I also use the same manifest file.